# Why rails select component cannot post empty array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

Provided that I write a diary edit page and set labels control like below:

```
<div class="field">
  <%= form.label :labels, for: 'diary_labels' %>
  <select id="diary_labels" name="diary[labels][]" multiple="" >
    <option value="label1">label1</option>
    <option value="label2">label2</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

If I select some data, such as "label1", then the put data will be:

```
{
  "diary": {
    "labels": ["label1"],
    ...
  }
}
```

However, if I select nothing, the put data actually be:

```
{
  "diary": {
    ...
  }
}
```

While I want is:

```
{
  "diary": {
    labels: [],
    ...
  }
}
```

How can I do it?

Comment: It's not rails it how html works

Comment: You can not send an empty array via HTTP, you can only send an array contains an empty string like `[""]`. You should handle this in controller